# Error 4608 : value out of range error in MS Word VBA (only in word 2007)

Tags: vba, ms-word

We have a macro in our word document which exports a PDF for each record in Mail Merge. When creating the doc, word always added a blank page to it, so we had to find a way to delete the last page (blank one). We added the `.Range(Lr - 1, TargetDoc.Range.End).Delete` line, and it worked perfectly; but only in Word > 2007 - when we tried running the macro in Word 2007, it said :

[image]

---

```
Option Explicit

Const FOLDER_SAVED As String = "F:\Postcard\" '//Makes sure your folder path ends with a backward slash
Const SOURCE_FILE_PATH As String = "G:\Laptop Data\GoaRegion.xlsm"

Sub TestRun()
Dim MainDoc As Document, TargetDoc As Document
Dim dbPath As String
Dim recordNumber As Long, totalRecord As Long
Dim Lr As Long

Set MainDoc = ActiveDocument
With MainDoc.MailMerge
    
        '// if you want to specify your data, insert a WHERE clause in the SQL statement
        .OpenDataSource Name:=SOURCE_FILE_PATH, sqlstatement:="SELECT * FROM [Goa$]"
            
        totalRecord = .DataSource.RecordCount

        For recordNumber = 1 To totalRecord
        
            With .DataSource
                .ActiveRecord = recordNumber
                .FirstRecord = recordNumber
                .LastRecord = recordNumber
            End With
            
            .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
            .Execute False
            
            Set TargetDoc = ActiveDocument
            
            With TargetDoc
                Lr = .GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToLast).Start
                .Range(Lr - 1, TargetDoc.Range.End).Delete
            End With
            
            TargetDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat FOLDER_SAVED & .DataSource.DataFields("Voter").Value & ".pdf", exportformat:=wdExportFormatPDF
                        
            TargetDoc.Close False
            
            Set TargetDoc = Nothing
                    
        Next recordNumber

End With

Set MainDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Is there something wrong? Does Word 2007 not support the line `.Range(Lr - 1, TargetDoc.Range.End).Delete`? Kindly guide... Thanks!

Comment: Work with the object model, not against it.  Test if the start of the range is in the same section as the end of the range.  If not, then delete the last section of the document

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If Not Application.Version = "12.0" Then
    With TargetDoc
        Lr = .GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToLast).Start
        .Range(Lr - 1, TargetDoc.Range.End).Delete
    End With
End If
```